# Issue with time complexity

Tags: recursion, tree, time-complexity

Okay the problem is quite simple, We need to find the count of all nodes in a complete binary tree.

I have tried to solve the question using the below given approach, but still having understanding the Time Complexity. Some agree as O(logN^2) whereas other say It is more than even O(N) so O(NlogN) maybe.
Kind Verify and also suggest some better approaches to solve this problem.

```
int countNodes(TreeNode* root) {
        if(!root)  return 0;
        int hl=0, hr=0;
        TreeNode *l=root, *r=root;
        while(l) { hl++; l=l->left; }
        while(r) { hr++; r=r->right;}
        if(hl==hr) return pow(2, hl)-1;
        return 1 + countNodes(root->left)+countNodes(root->right);
    }
```

Comment: what is `N` here ?

Comment: @mangusta: probably the number of items in the tree.

Comment: You can simply iterate over the items in tre tree, and keep track of the number, making it *O(n)*.

Comment: and it doesn't make sense to maintain `hl` and `hr`. as long as the tree is complete, they will be equal

Comment: this line: `return 1 + countNodes(root->left)+countNodes(root->right);` is useless, it's never reached. the recursion will always return 2^height-1. in fact there is no recursion at all. it will run the very first call and return

Comment: complexity is therefore `O(logN)`

Comment: @mangusta: a complete tree is *not* a *perfect* tree. The last level of the nodes can be partially filled.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply calculate the number of items on the left, and the items on the right, and sum these up:

```
int countNodes(TreeNode* root) {
    if(!root)  return 0;
    return 1 + countNodes(root->left)+countNodes(root->right);
}
```

If we assume that all arithmetic can be done in constant time (well this is actually the case, since an `int` has a fixed word size), it will result in at most *3×n* calls (since every leaf can make two extra calls, that each will be `null`), so this works in linear time.

Your optimization of calculating the leftmost item, and the rightmost item, is first of all incorrect, since if that is the case, and the nodes are unique in the tree, then that means the number of children is simply one. Even if you manage to get that working, it will not make a difference, since if the number of children is not one, we need to perform the calculating through recursion anyway.

A *complete* binary tree means that only the last layer can have `null`s instead of nodes. But that thus means that in the last layer, there will be at most *⌊n/2⌋+1*. We can perform binary search on that last layer to find out where the last layer stops, and this will indeed make it *O(log<sup>2</sup> n)*: an *O(log n)* for the binary search, but every query takes *O(h)* time to inspect, and since the height of the tree scales with *O(log n)*, we thus obtain *O(log<sup>2</sup>n)*. I leave it as an exercise to implement that.

Comment: I recommend you to revise your answer because his implementation is correct, except that redundant recursive call `return 1+ ...`. if the tree is complete, we simply need to find the height and return `2^height-1` which the OP is actually doing

Comment: @mangusta: a complete tree is not a *full* tree (https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#complete) a complete tree "*is a binary tree in which every level, **except possibly the last**, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible*". Only for a complete full tree (both conditions), the number of nodes is 2^h-1

Comment: ah, that's right. I confused full trees with complete ones

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not sure about the binary search approach. Can you please drop some code here. Would be glad!

Comment: @mangusta Can you please fix the redundancy part in the recursive part.